# Connect and disconnect USB devices programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb

I need to connect and disconnect USB devices, such as flash drives, in a programmatical manner, without unplugging and re-plugging the device.

Is there any way to do it in a C# Windows application?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at some related questions:

- [Safe remove USB-Drive using Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85649/safe-remove-usb-drive-using-win32-api)
- [Windows - Power off an usb device in software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404097/windows-power-off-an-usb-device-in-software)

Both of the approaches mentioned in the answers are readily translatable to C#.