# How can i turn off certain usb port

Tags: delphi, usb, drivers

Today i followed this instructable http://www.instructables.com/id/USB-Mini-Fan-1 .

I thought it would be cool to just stop the power on a certain usb port to stop the fan.Can i do that from code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows - Power off an usb device in software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404097/windows-power-off-an-usb-device-in-software)

Comment: Not possible. Also, duplicate, voted to close. Add an Atmel AVR, Arduino USB, or other similar microcontroller, and a small power control circuit and you can make a smart USB mini-fan, though, and then you can control it from software.

Comment: Delphi? Can Delphi make coffee for me too?

Comment: @user539484 If something can be done in user mode in other languages for shure it can be done in delphi, if it needs a device driver you can write it in C++ and interact with it from delphi application. I don't know what why are you so ironic .

Comment: @opc0de because it is easier to be 'smart' than giving a solution

Comment: You could do some research about USB (pretty well known subject!) before starting desperate seeking for **teh codez**. @RBA, i've seen your now deleted "solution", it is better to be smart, definitely.

Comment: @user539484 - being arrogant and ironic does not help anybody. my answer was deleted. I don't see any answer from you, only that you want Delhi to make you a coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to extend the DIY USB Fan with a USB circuit board implementing the switch ON/OFF logic with all the adaptations effort it takes.

**Edit:**

Visiting your profile (Romania), I presume that you are a bit comfortable with french and suggest you the following link:

- [Carte 8 relais sur port USB](http://www.planete-domotique.com/energie/arrosage/carte-8-relais-sur-port-usb.html)

Comment: i already have an arduino board i could easily make a hack but the idea was to output something low cost.I guess this is the only way to do it.Thanks.