# How to control my USB port using C#

Tags: c#, usb

What I want to write is an application that would be able to access my USB port.

To control when to charge my phone and when not to. And perhaps with time I would like to extend the application to control light bulbs, fans and the television in my room.

I want to learn how to work this out rather than just copy some line of codes and paste. I wish for a quick and very simplified tutorial on this, I would be highly grateful (small language please, You all know am still learning :-)).

The exact job I want to achieve is just to make the port send out power when needed. That is it should be switched off and on using codes if possible.

Comment: This question is way too broad. You need to identify a specific problem and show evidence you've attempted to solve it before anyone will consider helping you.

Comment: Check [Working with USB devices in .NET and C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/)

Comment: @KevinBrydon, made some edits, okay now?

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge, with your plans, you sir will be creating robots next week.

Comment: Your question is still to broad and is seems like you're asking someone to write the code for you. You should show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Your own code would be helpful.

Comment: @Philip, :-), cant tell, might happen, would happen

Comment: The question is actually very specific and has already been answered multiple times

Comment: oh come on, I do not see the relationship... I don't think its a duplicate at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to change the power status of a USB port from User mode code. It's not a .NET limitation, no user application can change the power status of a USB port. Actually, I think that the power state is controlled by the chipset itself and you can't turn it off without using a specialized chipset.

Besides, if your device short-circuited, you could  burn your chipset and your motherboard.

The only (safe) solution is to use an external device that will control a relay to turn power on or off for your devices.

There are multiple answers to similar questions, eg  [Windows- Power off a USB device in Software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404097/windows-power-off-an-usb-device-in-software)

A good option is to use an external device like [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) (or [Netduino](http://netduino.com/)), [.NET Gadgeteer](http://www.netmf.com/gadgeteer/) or any number of external boards. Prices and capabilities vary of course.

If you want to build the device yourself, you can find numerous USB relays with a simple Google search

**EDIT**

Regarding serial ports, there is almost no relation at all between the two port types. Serial ports are not designed to provide power. You can use tricks to use a pin's voltage to power some external device, although this will lead to problems because there is not enough current to power most devices. Burning the chipset is another likely outcome.

A USB port on the other hand, is explicitly designed [to provide  power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power) through specific wires which can't be controlled normally. This is why you can charge your phone from a desktop's USB port even if the machine has shut down.

**EDIT 2: Sleep-and-charge ports**
As Ben Voigt noted, not all USB ports allow charging while shutdown.

There are multiple port types that support charging. [Charging ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Charging_ports_and_accessory_charging_adapters) provide more current than plain ports but shut down when the computer is switched off. [Sleep-and-charge ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Sleep-and-charge_ports) on the other hand can provide power even when the computer is off.

Comment: hmm, but what about serial ports, If I am not mistaking, that's the way they work. They switch off and on pins

Comment: There is almost no relation at all between the two port types. Power in the USB port is not a separate controllable pin, which is why you can charge your phone from a desktop's USB port even if the machine has shut down.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You can't charge from a USB port which is turned off.  Some machines have special circuitry to supply the USB power through a different path when the main power is off, but this is not part of the USB specification, is the exception rather than the rule, and usually this function IS controllable.

Comment: @BenVoigt, not quite. There are many port types and Sleep-and-charge ports are just one type

Comment: I wouldn't really call that a "port type".  Port types are host, device, or OTG.  Perhaps a "power circuit type".

Comment: Well, that's what Wikipedia calls them. The linked "Battery Charging Specification" doesn't call them anything. Guess they didn't care so much about wording