# How to perform a hardware reset of a specific HID device?

Tags: delphi, winapi, hid

### The aim

Perform a hardware reset of a specific USB dongle ANT, HID device, with Delphi app.

---

### 1. CM_Request_Device_Eject function attempt

I have tried to use the [`CM_Request_Device_Eject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and it correctly ejects my device, but on some systems does not automatically start it again.

This is the code I've used for the device eject:

```
str := PChar(GetDeviceID(DeviceInfoData.DevInst));
status := CM_Locate_DevNodeA(dev, str, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);
status := CM_Request_Device_EjectA(dev, nil, '', 0, 0);
```

Is there a way to ensure that my device will start if it does not automatically start after eject when using this function ?

---

### 2. SetupDiRestartDevices function attempt

As an alternative I've tried to use the [`SetupDiRestartDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and this one properly resets my device, but except that resets all the HID devices (such as mouse, keyboard, etc.), and this function requires administrator rights to work:

```
rslt1 := SetupDiRestartDevices(hDevInfo, DeviceInfoData);
```

How can I reset only my device with this function ?

---

### Question

Is there a generic, recommended way to perform a hardware reset of a specific USB HID device ? Or is there a way to resolve any of the above problems ?

Comment: Have you tried using `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_HID_DEACTIVATE_DEVICE` and `IOCTL_HID_ACTIVATE_DEVICE` it depends on the vendor of the driver, but it may be worth a try

Comment: I don't think this would be possible to achieve per port, at best per hub maybe. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404097/power-off-an-usb-device-in-software-on-windows - http://superuser.com/a/132794

Answer (score 1):

Hard reset is not something you can do just of your own...
to do a hard reset to some device, that particular device must support hard reset...
ways hard reset varies from device to device.
some devices have a button on it to do a hard reset. some requires a piece of code. most of the company releases a set of AT-command lists for there specific devices..

for example.. 
[here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi244_qsN_PAhUJQY8KHX0WBlUQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sparkfun.com%2Fassets%2Flearn_tutorials%2F4%2F0%2F3%2F4A-ESP8266__AT_Instruction_Set__EN_v0.30.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFXeG4JPYXvSWXLkZp4_Nu-ymNvCg) is list of at commands released by the manufacturer for there specific device

[this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjV7-2GsN_PAhUGu48KHSBKApMQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F7%2Fd%2Fd%2F7dd44bb7-2a7a-4505-ac1c-7227d3d96d5b%2Fhid-over-i2c-protocol-spec-v1-0.docx&usg=AFQjCNFKgRu7pQwNLzeWz1sUHpx3kw18Jw) can help you in this case...
if not keep googling.