# How to power off USB device from Windows using batch or any API

Tags: api, batch-file, arm, usb, devcon

For testing purposes I need to power off a USB device from my computer programmatically. The microprocessor in the USB device is ARM Cortex M4.

I have tried using Devcon, although the device was disabled, power was still provided to the device.

I have also tried to disable the USB root hubs ,that also didn't work.

I have read some other posts indicating that a SSR could be used, this option is not desired. I would rather choose the software solution(if there is one of course).

Some other answers have indicated that this is an OS issue, and some others a chip-set architecture issue.

So my question is what options are there available. And also is this purely something dependent on the computer side or do we need to implement something on the USB device side as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question suits better to http://www.superuser.com/ in my opinion...

Comment: You can use an Integration of external tool called [RemoveDrive.exe](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) in a batch to regenerate after and use it. you can take a look at this example : [Copy2USB.bat](http://pastebin.com/HNZtQafz)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power off an USB device in software on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404097/power-off-an-usb-device-in-software-on-windows)

Comment: A USB port _has_ to provide enumeration power per the USB standard - as all the answers to the many existing variants of this question say, there is no generic way to physically disable that power, as it's often not possible short of unplugging the whole machine at the wall. If your device doesn't have the capability to fully power itself off on command, you're going to be best off with some controllable hub or switch in between.